# In Pycharm, Slow mouse interface(e.q. click button) when connecting server with terminal

Tags: python, user-interface, terminal, pycharm, x11

I have a difficulty with developing with pycharm (absolutely just installing pycharm)
I download "pycharm 2016.1" and initiate "pycharm.sh".
but I cannot do anything, because click interface is not working in the program window. It is very slowwwwwwwww.

Maybe, I think that it is setting problem. Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: The last version of pycharm lags like a hell. Even with increased `Xmx`,  even with `powersaved` mode on. For example If I just press any key and keep it held in editor pycharm freezes for 10-15 seconds eating one core of cpu. This all happens on `i7` `6700hq`, it's not like I'm using `atom`

Comment: Thank you a lot. I do not have a problem with local mode on i7,3.4Ghz. However, when connecting with terminal, GUI interface just stuck.

Comment: @deathangel908 and 정일채, could you file an issue in our tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com with idea.log attached? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files